# I want to give specific condition on the specific date but its not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

On a specific date I want to run some code but its not alerting on if condition.

```
var today=new Date(),
      dd = today.getDate().
      mm= today.getMonth()+1,
      yyyy=today.getYear()
     
     // its alerting
    // alert(dd);
```

If I  put in an if condition and comparing the date its not alerting.

```
// bt its not
If ( dd == 23) {
 alert("0");
      
}
```

I don't know what is the reason as
its not giving alert if I am matching the date in if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an error..there's nothing wrong with it *per se*...

`today.getDate().` <--- change trailing `period` to a `comma`.

change `If` to `if`

If you make those changes [as illustrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/gWEFv/) then it works fine

Comment: can i make it according to server side date ??

Comment: @Sachin Rawal Of course. But you'll need to use something to send the data between the server and the client, which we refer to as `Ajax`.

Comment: i will be glad if you will help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var today=new Date(),
          dd = today.getDate().
          mm= parseInt(today.getMonth())+1,
          yyyy=today.getYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a few corrections:

```
var today=new Date(),
    dd = today.getDate() // removed the period
    mm = parseInt(today.getMonth()) + 1,
    yyyy = today.getYear(); // added a semi-colon

    // its alerting
    // alert(dd);   

    if ( dd == 23) {
        alert("0");
    }
```